# OpenGL fog is based on Z-axis instead of depth

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to add fog to my scene, but instead of the scene becoming more foggy further away from the camera, the fog seems to be entirely dependent on height. Below is a screenshot demonstrating the problem:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ab60dfd1d85a3a5533153f09ef6a059e.png))</sub>

I initialize the fog using the following code:

```
gl.glFogx( GL10.GL_FOG_MODE, GL10.GL_LINEAR );
gl.glFogfv( GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, new float[] { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, 0 );
gl.glFogf( GL10.GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.35f );
gl.glHint( GL10.GL_FOG_HINT, GL10.GL_DONT_CARE );
gl.glFogf( GL10.GL_FOG_START, 10.0f );
gl.glFogf( GL10.GL_FOG_END, 15.0f );
gl.glEnable( GL10.GL_FOG );
```

And this is how my projection is set up:

```
gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_PROJECTION );
gl.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective( gl, 90.0f, _w / _h, 0.1f, 15.0f );
GLU.gluLookAt( gl, _player.position.x, _player.position.y, _player.position.z, centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your fog is being applied to the world coordinates, not the view ones. Not sure why though :/

Comment: Z-axis **is** the depth... You draw everything wrong. X is from left to right, Y is from bottom to top and Z is from far to near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you need to use GL_MODELVIEW for your camera.

See http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html

Answer (score 1):

Oh. You need to use gluLookAt for the GL_MODELVIEW matrix instead of GL_PROJECTION. What a d'oh moment.